# VBA Validation.Add method failed

Tags: vba, excel, validation, methods

So I opened a new Excel Worksheet just to learn more on Data Validation Creation via VBA and I entered the following code which was an example from Microsoft Developer Network website:

```
With Range("$E$5").Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _
 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="5", Formula2:="10"
 .InputTitle = "Integers"
 .ErrorTitle = "Integers"
 .InputMessage = "Enter an integer from five to ten"
 .ErrorMessage = "You must enter a number from five to ten"
End With
```

I got the following error when I executed the code:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Method 'Add' of object 'Validation' failed

I searched everywhere but did not find anything on the problem...

Comment: Do you have a validation in E5 set already? If so, try deleting it with `.Delete` before adding a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if there is already a validation for the desired cell. So if you run that code on a new worksheet it runs fine once but will fail the second time.

Therefore delete any validation before you add a new one.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$5").Validation
    .Delete 'delete validations first

    .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _
      AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="5", Formula2:="10"
    .InputTitle = "Integers"
    .ErrorTitle = "Integers"
    .InputMessage = "Enter an integer from five to ten"
    .ErrorMessage = "You must enter a number from five to ten"
End With
```

Note that you should always specify a sheet for your range like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range` to avoid any issues.

Comment: Okay, so I added the Delete method before the Add one and assured that there are no validations to that particular cell. When I ran the code again the same error occured. And the line for the particular sheet I used is actually: ' With Sheet1.Range("$E$5").Validation '. I don't think I have problems with that, but I will try the 'Worksheet("Sheet1")'

Comment: @V.Stoyanov This code definitely works, I tested it. If you still got any issues you need to post further information.

Comment: Ok, so I used the same code but on a 2016 version and it worked with no issues or errors. Still thank you for the support!